# javascript call instance method from static method using prototype

Tags: javascript, static, instance, static-methods, instance-methods

I know that it is normally not possible to call instance method from static method.

But, If I use prototype object then I could do in javascript.

```
class Foo {
  static helloStatic() {
    this.prototype.helloInstance();
  }

  helloInstance() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
}

Foo.helloStatic(); // 'hello'
```

I think the codes above will work similarly as the codes bellow.

```
var Foo = function() {};

Foo.prototype.helloInstance = function() {
  console.log('hello');
};

Foo.helloStatic = function() {
  this.prototype.helloInstance();
};

Foo.helloStatic(); // 'hello'
```

I think that helloInstance method is loaded in memory whenever the helloStatic function is called. So I think this way may result in unpredictable work.

But If I can avoid this malfunction, and don't use something like interval and timeout or some asynchronous work, in other words, If I use only safe work (like pure function), then Can I call instance method from static function and It is really safe? Otherwise, I wonder the reason that shouldn't do that.

Comment: + 

I want to use the static function like single-ton and the instance function like private method.

Comment: 1/2 ... Unless the OP does not explain what really needs to be achieved, there will mostly guessing be left for any answer. But with the OP's 1st sentence ... *"I know that it is normally not possible to call instance method from static method."* ... one can already shed light on it. The static class method from the given example does not call an *"instance method"* it just forwards the invocation to the final method that got nailed to the constructor's prototype ... `this.prototype.helloInstance`. The latter sits there as **"static"** as does the former with `Foo.helloStatic`.

Comment: 2/2 ... `helloInstance` exclusively acts as an *"instance method"* as soon as a `Foo` instance tries accessing it. Since such a type does not directly own this property, the prototype chain will be walked up until it was found. In case of an invocation, delegation will take place. Thus the found method will be called within the context of the very object that was looking for the non directly owned method. And just this delegation automatism should be referred to as *"instance method"*.